# R: subset dataframe by column value found in a separate vector, keeping duplicates

Tags: r, subset

Suppose I have a vector containing a sequence of radii in `a`, and the area and circumference for radii from 1 through 30 in `circle_stats`. I want to subset `circle_stats` such that the rows match those found in `a`.

```
a <- as.character(c(1,2,3,4,5,5,6,7,2,8,4,9,10,10,1,1,1,1,1,4))
unique(a[duplicated(a)])
# these are the duplicated values
# 5 2 4 10 1

radius <- c(1:30)
circle_stats <- data.frame(radius=as.character(radius),
                           area=pi*radius^2,
                           circumference=2*pi*radius)
```

**This would also mean being able to keep duplicates instead of discarding them**, or 20 rows subsetted from `circle_stats` instead of just 10.

This is what I tried:

```
library(data.table)
circle_stats %>% 
  subset(radius %in% a) %>%
  arrange(match(radius, a))

   radius       area circumference
1       1   3.141593      6.283185
2       2  12.566371     12.566371
3       3  28.274334     18.849556
4       4  50.265482     25.132741
5       5  78.539816     31.415927
6       6 113.097336     37.699112
7       7 153.938040     43.982297
8       8 201.061930     50.265482
9       9 254.469005     56.548668
10     10 314.159265     62.831853
```

As you can see, the issue is that I can't keep duplicates, which I assume requires an argument or function within the `subset` function. I just can't figure out which one.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

**edit: originally the question considered numerical values, but the dataset I'm working with uses character values in `a` and `circle_stats$radius`.**

Comment: Do you want `circle_stats %>% dplyr::slice(a)`?

Comment: @lotus Yes, thank you so much! But what if the dataset I'm actually contains characters, not numeric?

Comment: Something like `circle_stats %>% slice(match(a, radius))` should work in that case.

Comment: @lotus It's giving the same output as `circle_stats %>% subset(radius %in% a) %>%
  arrange(match(radius, a))`, I'm afraid.

Comment: Do you want to edit your question to be representative of your data?  Also are you sure that you used `match(a, radius)` and not `match(radius, a)`?

Comment: @lotus thank you, I've changed the question and you've also answered my question! ;D

Answer (score 2):

Thank you @lotus for the answer:

```
library(dplyr)
circle_stats %>% 
    dplyr::slice(match(a, radius))


   radius       area circumference
1       1   3.141593      6.283185
2       2  12.566371     12.566371
3       3  28.274334     18.849556
4       4  50.265482     25.132741
5       5  78.539816     31.415927
6       5  78.539816     31.415927
7       6 113.097336     37.699112
8       7 153.938040     43.982297
9       2  12.566371     12.566371
10      8 201.061930     50.265482
11      4  50.265482     25.132741
12      9 254.469005     56.548668
13     10 314.159265     62.831853
14     10 314.159265     62.831853
15      1   3.141593      6.283185
16      1   3.141593      6.283185
17      1   3.141593      6.283185
18      1   3.141593      6.283185
19      1   3.141593      6.283185
20      4  50.265482     25.132741
```